# Difference between Glucose, Fructose and Sucrose

Tags: sugar

What is the difference between:

- Glucose?
- Fructose?
- Sucrose?

I know they are all forms of sugar, and your body needs them.

**But what is what?**

OK, I do know that *"Fructose is a natural sugar found in a variety of foods such as fruit, honey and vegetables."*

What is normal sugar then, like the stuff you buy from the shops to put in your coffee?

Thanks

Comment: Nutrition topics unrelated to physical fitness or exercise is considered off-topic according to our [faq].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Glucose and Fructose are [monosaccharides](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monosaccharides), the simplest forms of sugars that your body can use directly.  Sucrose and high fructose corn syrup are [disaccharides](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disaccharide), or a larger more complex compound of glucose and fructose.  Sucrose, the type of table sugar from sugar cane or beet sugar, is 50% fructose and 50% glucose.  High fructose corn syrup is a [manufactured sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-fructose_corn_syrup) that is engineered to certain ratios:

- HFCS 55: 55% fructose to 45% glucose
- HFCS 42: 42% fructose to 53% glucose
- HFCS 90: 90% fructose to 10% glucose--usually used to blend with HFCS 42 to make HFCS 55

The health concerns usually revolve around the level of fructose more than glucose.  For example [fructose malabsorption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fructose_malabsorption) is fairly common.  Most commonly, the biggest concern is a [link between fructose and visceral fat](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/02/07/health/research/fructose-consumption-increases-visceral-fat-study-reports.html) levels.  Visceral fat is the fat below the muscle surface packed between your organs.  Too much visceral fat will cascade into several health disorders.  This is primarily a concern because [we have radically increased our fructose intake from 1970 to 2000](http://www.ajcn.org/content/86/4/895.full).

As with all things dietary, too much of any one thing is not healthy.  Your diet should be very balanced.

Comment: On the other side of things, glucose is what controls the glycemic index, which more directly controls insulin response, which in turn can make you hungry and relates to insulin sensitively.